# Pymodm connect to an mlab MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, data-modeling, pymodm

I have a MongoDB database hosted on mlab and I would like to use [PyMODM](http://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html) as my object modeling library.

This is my code so far:

```
from pymodm import connect, MongoModel, fields


connect = connect('mongodb://user:pass@ds119788.mlab.com/db')

class Test(MongoModel):
    user = fields.CharField()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test("test")
    test.save()
```

But it gives me this error :

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ds119788.mlab.com:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#connecting-to-mongodb

Comment: edited my question @Veeram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [MongoDB URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) provided by `mlab` for your account. The URI should contain the [port](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-port) number to connect to.

For example, it should look like :

```
connect = connect('mongodb://user:password@ds119788.mlab.com:63123/databaseName')
```

Comment: thank you @Wan, I was not passing the port properly.